# matlab assigning text file data to age and gender

Tags: arrays, matlab

Okay so my assignment is for an engineering project and I have talked to my teacher many times but without much success. the code reads data that comes from a rotary encoder in a text file. The question I have is how do I make two sets of arrays with age and gender and link it to each text file thats read in. For example the first text file comes from a girl that is 10; that spun a crank and output data to a text file. How do i code so that someway i can assign the first text file to an age and gender? Heres my code so far any help is appreciated.

```
%% ME 208 Project Group 21
clear; close all; clc;

%Constants
dt=.1;
%Translate Data
mass = 10; %values are in units of Kilograms
radius = 1; %values are in units of meters
inertia = mass*radius^(2);

for ii=1:2
    %File Name Variable
    filename=['sub_' num2str(ii) '.txt'];

    %Data is Collected
    Data1=dlmread(filename,'\t',0,0);

    %Times for data
    t1=dt:dt:length(Data1)*dt;

    %Vel
    [ang_vel1, ang_acc1]=dxdt_d2xdt2(Data1,2,dt);

    torq1 = inertia*ang_acc1;

    %Calculations of parameters
    meanrt1(ii) = rms(torq1);
    maxrt1(ii) = max(torq1);

end
%Plot
figure(1);plot(t1,torq1,t2,torq2); grid minor;
```

Comment: Your code seems to have no relation to your problem description. Although the description is difficult to follow, I cannot reconcile age and gender with mass, radius and inertia.

Comment: The code computes torq from the file that has rotational values. I simply want to relate each data text file to the user creating the data. The code will then compute torq